# Solaris Nags About "process.max-stack-size" while running "Java Processes"

Tags: java, configuration-management, solaris-10, resource-management

I have a server running Solaris 10. It reports **using 10% of total** memory using prstat. I 've ran process using Java 1.7.0_80 in 64-bit mode.
The problem is that System always nags about process.max-stack-size ***no matter how much I change the stack size*** of related project on `/etc/projects` and re-lunching the app ( Screen shot attached)
**Should I use any specific tunning to run java applications on Solaris 10?**
Why program does not show any error and run perfectly while solaris nags about stack limitation?

[image]

Comment: This is not a error message is a notice message, messages may be quieted in syslog by using `rctladm -d syslog process.max-stack-size`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's nagging to give the SA an idea that something might be going on with the box.

I also have a suspicion that you may be working in a zone.  If so, it may have some resource restrictions imposed on it.

Reco you talk to your SA.

Comment: the server is in global zone